# How can I print the results from this script? I can't get any results in my IDE

Tags: python

I am trying to see the results for this script in Spyder, but I can't get it to print and I'm not sure how. I tried print(options), print(opt), print(exps), but nothing seems to be working. I don't get any "errors" either... I just get the normal In[number]: runfile(my path)

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

def options_chain(symbol):

    tk = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    # Expiration dates
    exps = tk.options

    # Get options for each expiration
    options = pd.DataFrame()
    for e in exps:
        opt = tk.option_chain(e)
        opt = pd.DataFrame().append(opt.calls).append(opt.puts)
        opt['expirationDate'] = e
        options = options.append(opt, ignore_index=True)
        

    # Bizarre error in yfinance that gives the wrong expiration date
    # Add 1 day to get the correct expiration date
    options['expirationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(options['expirationDate']) + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    options['dte'] = (options['expirationDate'] - datetime.datetime.today()).dt.days / 365
    
    # Boolean column if the option is a CALL
    options['CALL'] = options['contractSymbol'].str[4:].apply(
        lambda x: "C" in x)
    
    options[['bid', 'ask', 'strike']] = options[['bid', 'ask', 'strike']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    options['mark'] = (options['bid'] + options['ask']) / 2 # Calculate the midpoint of the bid-ask
    
    # Drop unnecessary and meaningless columns
    options = options.drop(columns = ['contractSize', 'currency', 'change', 'percentChange', 'lastTradeDate', 'lastPrice'])
    
    return options
    print(options)
```

Comment: You define a function, but you never call it, so this file does nothing.  Is there more code you aren't showing us?

Comment: please add your 'not working' print code.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the code in this post:

https://medium.com/@txlian13/webscrapping-options-data-with-python-and-yfinance-e4deb0124613

and that appears to be it for the code provided. I did import datettime since it wasn't in the raw code provided, but I'm not sure how to get the same results printed as the one in the page. when I add the line "print(options)" after "return(options", I don't get any error messages, but nothing prints. How can I get the results to display? From my understanding, I thought the function was defined as options?